# Multiple Pickerviews

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I want to build a viewcontroller which contains three pickerviews (which has three same options). I am having problems on how to show one specific row to the label. My code:

I changed other parts still getting errors. Edited variables' first letters to lowercase.

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var picker2: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var picker3: UIPickerView!

var Array  = ["Shake","Swipe Up","Swipe Right"]



@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!

var placementAnswer = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    picker1.delegate = self
    picker1.dataSource = self
    picker1.tag = 1

    picker2.delegate = self
    picker2.dataSource = self
    picker2.tag = 2

    picker3.delegate = self
    picker3.dataSource = self
    picker3.tag = 3

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return Array[row]

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return Array.count
}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

@IBAction func save3(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func save2(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func save1(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    if (placementAnswer == 0){
        label1.text = "Shake"
    }

    else if(placementAnswer == 1){
        label1.text = "Swipe Up"

    }
    else{
        label1.text = "Swipe Right"
    }


    if (placementAnswer == 0){
        label2.text = "Shake"
    }

    else if(placementAnswer == 1){
        label2.text = "Swipe Up"

    }
    else{
        label2.text = "Swipe Right"

    }
    if (placementAnswer == 0){
        label3.text = "Shake"

    }
    else if(placementAnswer == 1){
        label3.text = "Swipe Up"

    }
    else{
        label3.text = "Swipe Right"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    picker1.delegate = self
    picker1.dataSource = self
    picker1.tag = 1

    picker2.delegate = self
    picker2.dataSource = self
    picker1.tag = 2

    picker3.delegate = self
    picker3.dataSource = self
    picker1.tag = 3

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        // do things for pickerview 1
        label1.text = row
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        // do things for pickerview 2
        label2.text = row
    }else {
        // do for pickerview 3
    }

    placementAnswer = row
}
}
```

Comment: why do you have __two__ `-viewDidLoad()` method?

Comment: I also dont know. When I delete either, I get errors.

Comment: I deleted the second one. it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate by using `tag`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    picker1.delegate = self
    picker1.dataSource = self
    picker1.tag = 1

    picker2.delegate = self
    picker2.dataSource = self
    picker1.tag = 2

    picker3.delegate = self
    picker3.dataSource = self
    picker1.tag = 3
}
```

so in your delegate methods just check the tag

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return Array[row]

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        // do things for pickerview 1
        Label1.text = Array[row]
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        // do things for pickerview 2
        Label2.text = Array[row]
    }else {
        // do for pickerview 3
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by //do things for pickerview 1? I am really new in coding @h44f33z

Comment: @VonRalphMarquez i update for the method where pickerview options is selected. so you could detect which pickerview is currently select by user

Comment: I'm getting this error: Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type ' String?' in these lines:

Comment: Label1.text = row

Comment: just update to `array[row]`. please avoid using variable with Uppercase in first letter and using the same name as Swift `Array` class :)

Comment: got it. now, I am getting error in viewDidLoad:  invalid redeclaration.

Comment: got it. Now, the problem is, the chosen row goes out in the label even if the Save button is not clicked. When I click the first Save button of the first pickerview, all of the labels of other pickerviews change.

Comment: how can i add a screenshot file? @h44f33z

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here you are @ h44f33z. How I can make each section dependent with each other? for example, if i choose "shake" for behavior name 1, it wont be available for behavior name 2 and 3. Each behavior name section will have one corresponding action. thanks!

Comment: @h44f33z here's the image.

Comment: I will be using the data in this view controller to the gesture pad view controller. So if  shake or Swipe gesture is done, the name of the behavior and corresponding gesture will appear on the screen, maybe through alert? @h44f33z.